# How do you read load averages? (eg: Load Averages: 0.60 0.60 0.55)

Tags: linux, unix, usage, stats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to understand the memory usage and load average in linux server](https://serverfault.com/questions/67759/how-to-understand-the-memory-usage-and-load-average-in-linux-server)

My hosting company provides "Load Average" stats when I login. There is no link to more information about them, and no explanation as to what they mean. I'm guessing they are a percentage, but I have no clue why there are three numbers, or what the percentage is actually out of (processor, memory, bandwidth, combination?), and is that this instant or over time? Is this a standard statistic that I should know about?

What are high / low / normal numbers?

Perhaps someone can shed some light on this for me.

Examples:

Load Averages: 0.60 0.60 0.55

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three numbers represent the number of processes, on average, that are ready to run but are blocked, over the last one, five, and fifteen minutes, respectively.

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Load_average

It varies very slightly from one unix-like OS to the next (e.g., different criteria for "waiting"), but they all work basically the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Load averages measure the trend in CPU utilization by calculating all demand for the CPU over a period of time, which can be thought of as a moving average. The important point to notice is that the value decreases with age. **The figures (which are read left to right) do not include any processes or threads waiting on I/O, networking, databases or anything else not demanding the CPU**. It only focuses on what actively demands CPU time, which is entirely different from CPU percentage.

By using the function y == (2^11/2^((5 Log2[E])/(60 x))) with the parameters of the load-average bucket, a constant exponent, and the number of running/uninterruptible processes, an exponential decay function is produced. (EXP_1 / 1 min. average, EXP_5 / 5 min. average and EXP_15 / 15 min. average).

For example if there are four CPUs on a server and it reported a one-minute load average of 4.00, then this indicates the machine has been utilizing its processors perfectly during the past 60 seconds.