# openvz containers optimization

Tags: centos, virtualization, virtual-machines, openvz

I am trying to optimize 14 containers on 64 G.B ram , 16 Core processor based on Centos 5.9 Final 64 Bit Distribution

The load average of the server up to 300

This is my memory stats

```
# vzmemcheck -v
Output values in %
CTID        LowMem  LowMem     RAM MemSwap MemSwap   Alloc   Alloc   Alloc
              util  commit    util    util  commit    util  commit   limit
101           0.04   13.85    0.47    0.34    6.31    0.58    6.31    8.62
200           0.04   13.85    0.50    0.36    5.16    0.82    5.16    6.01
130           0.03   13.85    0.34    0.24    5.16    0.62    5.16    5.74
109           0.02    0.08    0.08    0.05    0.14    0.25    0.17    0.33
105           0.04   13.85    0.49    0.36    6.31    0.95    6.31    6.01
104           0.03   13.85    0.20    0.14    5.16    0.38    5.16    4.39
103           0.04    0.08    0.60    0.43    0.14    0.65    0.17    3.78
102           0.03    0.08    0.35    0.25    0.14    0.49    0.17    0.58
210           0.05   13.85    0.78    0.56   17.84    0.90   17.84   13.23
190           0.03    0.08    0.37    0.27    0.14    0.59    0.17    2.03
215           0.04   13.85    0.49    0.36    4.30    0.57    4.30    5.16
160           0.01    0.08    0.10    0.07    0.14    0.20    0.17    3.78
150           0.04    0.08    0.39    0.28    0.14    0.56    0.17    2.03
140           0.03    0.08    0.26    0.19    0.14    0.39    0.17    2.09
110           0.12   13.85    0.99    0.72    6.31    1.35    6.31   13.23
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Summary:      0.58  111.39    6.41    4.64   57.52    9.31   57.76   76.99
```

vzubc ouput

```
# vzubc
----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 101       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|10.7M 0.5% 0.5%|23.8M   1%   1%|   2G|   2G|    -
  lockedpages|  22M 0.6% 0.6%|  22M 0.6% 0.6%|3.81G|3.81G|    -
  privvmpages| 623M  15%  15%|2.03G  50%  50%|   4G|   4G|    -
     shmpages| 608K   -    - |1.62M 0.1% 0.1%|   2G|   2G|    -
      numproc|  98    -    - | 223    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    physpages| 312M   -    - | 680M   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   2G|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 312M  15%   - | 680M  33%   - |   2G|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  40    -    - | 154    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
     numflock|  25    -    - |  47    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    -    - | 488K| 488K|    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  24    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    tcpsndbuf| 888K 0.4% 0.2%|3.51M   2% 0.9%| 204M| 378M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 640K 0.3% 0.2%|10.6M   5%   2%| 204M| 378M|    -
 othersockbuf| 103K   -    - |2.42M   1% 0.6%| 204M| 378M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - | 233K 0.1% 0.1%| 204M| 378M|    -
 numothersock|  65    -    - | 207    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
   dcachesize| 835K   -    - |5.05M 0.2% 0.2%|   2G|   2G|    -
      numfile|3.47K   -    - |9.86K   -    - |22.9M|22.9M|    -
    numiptent|  80    -    - |  80    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 200       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|11.3M 0.6% 0.6%|28.9M   1%   1%|   2G|   2G|    -
  lockedpages|  22M 0.6% 0.6%|22.1M 0.6% 0.6%|3.81G|3.81G|    4
  privvmpages| 741M  74%  41%|1.16G 119%  66%| 997M|1.74G|   78K
     shmpages| 259M  25%  25%| 519M  50%  50%|   1G|   1G|    -
      numproc|  72    -    - | 135    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    physpages| 328M   -    - | 636M   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   1G|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 328M  32%   - | 636M  62%   - |   1G|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  32    -    - | 276    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
     numflock|  18    -    - |  36    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   1    -    - | 488K| 488K|    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  28    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    tcpsndbuf| 603K 0.3% 0.2%|8.93M   4%   2%| 204M| 378M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 512K 0.2% 0.1%|4.31M   2%   1%| 204M| 378M|    -
 othersockbuf|68.7K   -    - | 921K 0.4% 0.2%| 204M| 378M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - |17.9K   -    - | 204M| 378M|    -
 numothersock|  43    -    - |  95    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
   dcachesize| 730K   -    - | 943K   -    - |   2G|   2G|    -
      numfile|   3K   -    - |3.49K   -    - |22.9M|22.9M|    -
    numiptent|  57    -    - |  57    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 130       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|6.94M 0.3% 0.3%|35.1M   2%   2%|   2G|   2G|    -
  lockedpages|  22M 0.6% 0.6%|22.1M 0.6% 0.6%|3.81G|3.81G|    -
  privvmpages| 531M  34%  34%|4.01G 267% 267%| 1.5G| 1.5G|  459K
     shmpages|32.6M   3%   3%|65.1M   6%   6%|   1G|   1G|    -
      numproc|  73    -    - | 384    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    physpages| 207M   -    - |2.62G   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   1G|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 207M  20%   - |2.62G 262%   - |   1G|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  25    -    - | 166    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
     numflock|  20    -    - | 121    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    -    - | 488K| 488K|    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - | 115    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    tcpsndbuf| 432K 0.2% 0.1%|8.79M   4%   2%| 204M| 378M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 400K 0.2% 0.1%|2.59M   1% 0.7%| 204M| 378M|    -
 othersockbuf|75.3K   -    - |4.26M   2%   1%| 204M| 378M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - |33.3K   -    - | 204M| 378M|    -
 numothersock|  46    -    - | 239    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
   dcachesize| 703K   -    - |7.62M 0.4% 0.4%|   2G|   2G|    -
      numfile|1.77K   -    - |12.1K 0.1% 0.1%|22.9M|22.9M|    -
    numiptent|  55    -    - |  70    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 109       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|3.71M  27%  26%|11.5M  83%  81%|13.7M|14.1M|    -
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |22.1M 275% 275%|   8M|   8M|    4
  privvmpages| 216M  84%  79%|   1G 400% 376%| 256M| 272M|  894
     shmpages|   4K   -    - |3.23M   3%   3%|  84M|  84M|   14
      numproc|  37   15%  15%| 107   44%  44%| 240 | 240 |    -
    physpages|44.4M   -    - | 369M   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 132M|   - |    -
 oomguarpages|44.4M  43%   - | 369M 362%   - | 102M|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  19    5%   5%|  61   16%  16%| 360 | 360 |    -
     numflock|  16    8%   7%|  30   16%  14%| 188 | 206 |    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   1    1%   1%| 100 | 100 |    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  60   23%  23%| 256 | 256 |    -
    tcpsndbuf| 188K  11%   7%|1.02M  62%  39%|1.64M|2.58M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 192K  11%   7%|1.65M 100%  64%|1.64M|2.58M| 1.24K
 othersockbuf|64.9K   5%   3%| 177K  16%   8%|1.07M|   2M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - |21.4K   8%   8%| 256K| 256K|    -
 numothersock|  36   10%  10%|  61   16%  16%| 360 | 360 |    -
   dcachesize| 504K  15%  14%| 794K  23%  22%|3.25M|3.46M|    -
      numfile|1.14K  12%  12%|3.19K  35%  35%|9.09K|9.09K|    -
    numiptent|  66    6%   6%|  80    8%   8%|1000 |1000 |    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 105       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|11.3M 0.6% 0.6%|73.1M   3%   3%|   2G|   2G|    -
  lockedpages|  22M 0.6% 0.6%|22.1M 0.6% 0.6%|3.81G|3.81G|    4
  privvmpages| 888M  89%  50%|4.06G 416% 233%| 997M|1.74G| 50.3K
     shmpages| 259M  12%  12%| 519M  25%  25%|   2G|   2G|    -
      numproc|  90    -    - | 566  0.1% 0.1%| 976K| 976K|    -
    physpages| 323M   -    - |1.66G   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   2G|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 323M  15%   - |1.66G  82%   - |   2G|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  42    -    - | 309    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
     numflock|  20    -    - |  39    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    -    - | 488K| 488K|    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - | 114    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    tcpsndbuf| 721K 0.3% 0.2%|5.51M   2%   2%| 204M| 378M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 672K 0.3% 0.2%|5.98M   2%   2%| 204M| 378M|    -
 othersockbuf|86.6K   -    - | 4.9M   2%   1%| 204M| 378M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - | 137K 0.1%   - | 204M| 378M|    -
 numothersock|  63    -    - | 409    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
   dcachesize| 768K   -    - |2.16M 0.1% 0.1%|   2G|   2G|    -
      numfile|2.93K   -    - |8.43K   -    - |22.9M|22.9M|    -
    numiptent|  80    -    - |  80    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 104       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|6.21M 0.3% 0.3%|22.4M   1%   1%|   2G|   2G| 7.31K
  lockedpages|  22M 0.6% 0.6%|22.1M 0.6% 0.6%|3.81G|3.81G|   16
  privvmpages| 319M  93%  93%|1.51G 452% 452%| 340M| 340M|  101K
     shmpages| 608K 0.1% 0.1%| 260M  25%  25%|   1G|   1G|    -
      numproc|  72    -    - | 259    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    physpages| 124M   -    - | 507M   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   1G|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 124M  12%   - | 507M  49%   - |   1G|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  39    -    - | 154    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
     numflock|   6    -    - |  31    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    -    - | 488K| 488K|    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  84    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    tcpsndbuf| 699K 0.3% 0.2%|2.28M   1% 0.6%| 204M| 378M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 624K 0.3% 0.2%| 5.1M   2%   1%| 204M| 378M|    -
 othersockbuf|68.7K   -    - |1.23M 0.6% 0.3%| 204M| 378M|  310
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - | 390K 0.2% 0.1%| 204M| 378M|    -
 numothersock|  43    -    - | 145    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
   dcachesize| 579K   -    - | 967K   -    - |   2G|   2G|    -
      numfile|1.53K   -    - |4.49K   -    - |22.9M|22.9M|    -
    numiptent|  55    -    - |  80    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 103       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|8.84M  64%  62%|19.3M 140% 136%|13.7M|14.1M|  462
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |22.1M 275% 275%|   8M|   8M|   24
  privvmpages| 568M  22%  17%|   2G  79%  61%| 2.5G|3.26G|  6.3K
     shmpages| 608K 0.7% 0.7%| 264M 315% 315%|  84M|  84M|    7
      numproc|  62   25%  25%| 133   55%  55%| 240 | 240 |    -
    physpages| 378M   -    - | 579M   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 132M|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 378M 371%   - | 579M 568%   - | 102M|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  30    8%   8%|  91   25%  25%| 360 | 360 |    -
     numflock|  39   20%  18%|  84   44%  40%| 188 | 206 |    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    2%   2%| 100 | 100 |    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  55   21%  21%| 256 | 256 |    -
    tcpsndbuf| 207K  12%   7%|5.45M 331% 211%|1.64M|2.58M|  733K
    tcprcvbuf| 209K  12%   7%|4.18M 254% 162%|1.64M|2.58M|  981
 othersockbuf|74.7K   6%   3%| 479K  43%  23%|1.07M|   2M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - |16.6K   6%   6%| 256K| 256K|    -
 numothersock|  44   12%  12%|  72   20%  20%| 360 | 360 |    -
   dcachesize| 762K  22%  21%|3.56M 109% 103%|3.25M|3.46M|    -
      numfile| 1.7K  18%  18%|7.69K  84%  84%|9.09K|9.09K|    -
    numiptent|  80    8%   8%|  80    8%   8%|1000 |1000 |    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 102       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|6.71M  49%  47%|79.8M 582% 566%|13.7M|14.1M| 6.61K
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |22.1M 275% 275%|   8M|   8M|   48
  privvmpages| 435M  96%  88%|4.06G 921% 848%| 450M| 489M| 91.9K
     shmpages| 608K 0.7% 0.7%| 519M 618% 618%|  84M|  84M|    6
      numproc|  56   23%  23%| 570  237% 237%| 240 | 240 |    -
    physpages| 223M   -    - |1.68G   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 132M|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 223M 218%   - |1.68G 1688%   - | 102M|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  40   11%  11%| 334   92%  92%| 360 | 360 |    -
     numflock|  66   35%  32%| 172   91%  83%| 188 | 206 |    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   1    1%   1%| 100 | 100 |    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - | 112   43%  43%| 256 | 256 |    -
    tcpsndbuf| 202K  12%   7%|5.86M 357% 227%|1.64M|2.58M|    3
    tcprcvbuf| 230K  13%   8%|5.22M 318% 202%|1.64M|2.58M|    -
 othersockbuf| 236K  21%  11%|3.73M 347% 186%|1.07M|   2M|  804
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - | 356K 139% 139%| 256K| 256K|    -
 numothersock|  50   13%  13%| 360  100% 100%| 360 | 360 |    -
   dcachesize| 907K  27%  25%|6.69M 205% 193%|3.25M|3.46M|    -
      numfile|1.87K  20%  20%|11.1K 121% 121%|9.09K|9.09K|    -
    numiptent|  80    8%   8%|  80    8%   8%|1000 |1000 |    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 210       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|9.29M 0.5% 0.5%|28.3M   1%   1%|   2G|   2G| 12.1K
  lockedpages|  22M 0.6% 0.6%|22.1M 0.6% 0.6%|3.81G|3.81G|   12
  privvmpages| 906M  11%  11%|3.82G  47%  47%|   8G|   8G|  768K
     shmpages| 612K   -    - |3.16M   -    - |  12G|  12G|    -
      numproc|  87    -    - | 276    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    physpages| 559M   -    - |2.96G   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |  12G|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 559M   4%   - |2.96G  24%   - |  12G|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  55    -    - | 226    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
     numflock|  11    -    - |  25    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    -    - | 488K| 488K|    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - | 211    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    tcpsndbuf|1.42M 0.7% 0.4%|11.4M   5%   3%| 204M| 378M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 880K 0.4% 0.2%|4.45M   2%   1%| 204M| 378M|    -
 othersockbuf|91.7K   -    - |2.13M   1% 0.6%| 204M| 378M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - | 855K 0.4% 0.2%| 204M| 378M|    -
 numothersock|  64    -    - | 206    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
   dcachesize| 789K   -    - | 2.8M 0.1% 0.1%|   2G|   2G|    -
      numfile|2.07K   -    - |8.08K   -    - |22.9M|22.9M|    -
    numiptent|  57    -    - |  71    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 190       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|8.08M  58%  57%|20.1M 146% 142%|13.7M|14.1M|    8
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |22.1M 275% 275%|   8M|   8M|   12
  privvmpages| 533M  53%  30%|3.36G 345% 193%| 997M|1.74G|  310K
     shmpages| 632K 0.7% 0.7%|1.77G 2159% 2159%|  84M|  84M|  822
      numproc|  70   29%  29%| 173   72%  72%| 240 | 240 |    -
    physpages| 243M   -    - | 576M   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 132M|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 243M 238%   - | 576M 565%   - | 102M|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  25    6%   6%|  85   23%  23%| 360 | 360 |    -
     numflock|   7    3%   3%|  40   21%  19%| 188 | 206 |    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    2%   2%| 100 | 100 |    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  61   23%  23%| 256 | 256 |    -
    tcpsndbuf| 205K  12%   7%|1.97M 120%  76%|1.64M|2.58M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 208K  12%   7%|4.87M 296% 188%|1.64M|2.58M|    4K
 othersockbuf|80.8K   7%   3%|1.24M 115%  62%|1.07M|   2M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - |51.2K  20%  20%| 256K| 256K|    -
 numothersock|  48   13%  13%| 178   49%  49%| 360 | 360 |    -
   dcachesize| 662K  19%  18%| 824K  24%  23%|3.25M|3.46M|    -
      numfile|1.65K  18%  18%|4.35K  47%  47%|9.09K|9.09K|    -
    numiptent|  28    2%   2%| 204   20%  20%|1000 |1000 |    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   7M   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 215       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|8.56M 0.4% 0.4%|30.5M   2%   2%|   2G|   2G|    -
  lockedpages|  22M 0.6% 0.6%|22.1M 0.6% 0.6%|3.81G|3.81G|   12
  privvmpages| 483M  47%  47%|2.06G 205% 205%|   1G|   1G|  153K
     shmpages| 608K 0.2% 0.2%| 519M 202% 202%| 256M| 256M|   20
      numproc|  62    -    - | 175    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    physpages| 295M   -    - | 761M   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 256M|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 295M 115%   - | 761M 297%   - | 256M|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  26    -    - | 157    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
     numflock|  21    -    - |  31    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    -    - | 488K| 488K|    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  48    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    tcpsndbuf| 445K 0.2% 0.1%|4.04M   2%   1%| 204M| 378M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 454K 0.2% 0.1%|5.08M   2%   1%| 204M| 378M|    -
 othersockbuf|79.3K   -    - | 575K 0.3% 0.1%| 204M| 378M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - | 224K 0.1% 0.1%| 204M| 378M|    -
 numothersock|  48    -    - | 254    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
   dcachesize| 734K   -    - | 927K   -    - |   2G|   2G|    -
      numfile|2.24K   -    - |4.23K   -    - |22.9M|22.9M|    -
    numiptent|  55    -    - |  80    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |12.1M   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 180       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|   -    -    - |79.5M   3%   3%|   2G|   2G|    -
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |22.1M 0.6% 0.6%|3.81G|3.81G|    8
  privvmpages|   -    -    - |2.49G  62%  62%|   4G|   4G|    -
     shmpages|   -    -    - | 264M  12%  12%|   2G|   2G|   77
      numproc|   -    -    - | 432    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    physpages|   -    -    - | 1.8G   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   2G|   - |    -
 oomguarpages|   -    -    - | 1.8G  89%   - |   2G|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|   -    -    - | 434    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
     numflock|   -    -    - |  46    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    -    - | 488K| 488K|    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  48    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    tcpsndbuf|67.4K   -    - |11.9M   5%   3%| 204M| 378M|    -
    tcprcvbuf|   -    -    - |6.94M   3%   2%| 204M| 378M|    -
 othersockbuf|   -    -    - |6.73M   3%   2%| 204M| 378M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - | 452K 0.2% 0.1%| 204M| 378M|    -
 numothersock|   -    -    - | 384    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
   dcachesize|   -    -    - |   2M 0.1% 0.1%|   2G|   2G|    -
      numfile|   -    -    - |10.3K   -    - |22.9M|22.9M|    -
    numiptent|   -    -    - |  57    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |26.2M   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 160       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|2.92M  21%  20%|8.61M  62%  61%|13.7M|14.1M|    -
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |  20K 0.2% 0.2%|   8M|   8M|    -
  privvmpages| 178M   7%   5%|1.89G  75%  57%| 2.5G|3.26G|   57
     shmpages| 124K 0.1% 0.1%|2.75M   3%   3%|  84M|  84M|    -
      numproc|  26   10%  10%|  93   38%  38%| 240 | 240 |    -
    physpages|61.7M   -    - |1.43G   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 132M|   - |    -
 oomguarpages|61.7M  60%   - |1.43G 1435%   - | 102M|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|   4    1%   1%|  45   12%  12%| 360 | 360 |    -
     numflock|   8    4%   3%|  17    9%   8%| 188 | 206 |    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   1    1%   1%| 100 | 100 |    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  67   26%  26%| 256 | 256 |    -
    tcpsndbuf|68.5K   4%   2%|1.31M  80%  50%|1.64M|2.58M|    -
    tcprcvbuf|  64K   3%   2%|2.72M 165% 105%|1.64M|2.58M|    -
 othersockbuf|9.12K 0.8% 0.4%|41.1K   3%   2%|1.07M|   2M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - |16.6K   6%   6%| 256K| 256K|    -
 numothersock|  10    2%   2%|  28    7%   7%| 360 | 360 |    -
   dcachesize| 349K  10%   9%| 560K  16%  15%|3.25M|3.46M|    -
      numfile| 660    7%   7%|3.37K  37%  37%|9.09K|9.09K|    -
    numiptent|  24    2%   2%|  24    2%   2%|1000 |1000 |    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 150       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|9.84M  71%  69%|39.2M 285% 277%|13.7M|14.1M| 46.2K
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |22.1M 275% 275%|   8M|   8M|    8
  privvmpages| 514M  51%  28%|1.05G 108%  60%| 997M|1.74G| 47.6K
     shmpages| 600K 0.7% 0.7%|1.09M   1%   1%|  84M|  84M|    -
      numproc|  69   28%  28%| 208   86%  86%| 240 | 240 |    -
    physpages| 260M   -    - | 769M   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 132M|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 260M 255%   - | 769M 754%   - | 102M|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  32    8%   8%| 222   61%  61%| 360 | 360 |    -
     numflock|   7    3%   3%|  33   17%  16%| 188 | 206 |    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    2%   2%| 100 | 100 |    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  47   18%  18%| 256 | 256 |    -
    tcpsndbuf| 205K  12%   7%|4.31M 262% 167%|1.64M|2.58M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 200K  11%   7%|4.48M 273% 173%|1.64M|2.58M|  488
 othersockbuf| 249K  22%  12%|2.16M 200% 107%|1.07M|   2M|   71
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - | 254K  99%  99%| 256K| 256K|   37
 numothersock|  57   15%  15%| 199   55%  55%| 360 | 360 |    -
   dcachesize| 705K  21%  19%| 926K  27%  26%|3.25M|3.46M|    -
      numfile| 1.7K  18%  18%|4.18K  46%  46%|9.09K|9.09K|    -
    numiptent|  57    5%   5%|  57    5%   5%|1000 |1000 |    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 140       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|6.41M  46%  45%|17.1M 124% 121%|13.7M|14.1M|    -
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |22.1M 275% 275%|   8M|   8M|   12
  privvmpages| 340M  32%  18%|   1G  98%  55%|1.01G|1.79G| 33.4K
     shmpages| 600K 0.7% 0.7%|1.09M   1%   1%|  84M|  84M|    -
      numproc|  54   22%  22%| 170   70%  70%| 240 | 240 |    -
    physpages| 160M   -    - | 360M   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 132M|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 160M 156%   - | 360M 353%   - | 102M|   - |    -
   numtcpsock|  26    7%   7%| 104   28%  28%| 360 | 360 |    -
     numflock|  15    8%   7%|  26   13%  12%| 188 | 206 |    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    2%   2%| 100 | 100 |    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  53   20%  20%| 256 | 256 |    -
    tcpsndbuf| 205K  12%   7%|1.74M 106%  67%|1.64M|2.58M|    -
    tcprcvbuf| 208K  12%   7%|3.14M 191% 121%|1.64M|2.58M|    -
 othersockbuf|  77K   7%   3%|1.14M 106%  57%|1.07M|   2M|    -
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - |10.8K   4%   4%| 256K| 256K|    -
 numothersock|  45   12%  12%| 229   63%  63%| 360 | 360 |    -
   dcachesize| 697K  21%  19%| 917K  27%  25%|3.25M|3.46M|    -
      numfile| 1.5K  16%  16%|3.97K  43%  43%|9.09K|9.09K|    -
    numiptent| 204   20%  20%| 204   20%  20%|1000 |1000 |    -
    swappages|   -    -    - |   4K   -    - |   - |   - |    -

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 110       | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|29.8M   2%   2%|67.2M   3%   3%|   2G|   2G|  859
  lockedpages|  22M 0.6% 0.6%|22.1M 0.6% 0.6%|3.81G|3.81G|   32
  privvmpages| 1.2G  15%  15%|4.01G  50%  50%|   8G|   8G| 96.7K
     shmpages| 259M  12%  12%| 778M  38%  38%|   2G|   2G|    6
      numproc| 224    -    - | 699  0.1% 0.1%| 976K| 976K|    1
    physpages| 639M   -    - |1.25G   -    - |   - |   - |    -
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   2G|   - |    -
 oomguarpages| 639M  31%   - |1.25G  62%   - |   2G|   - |    -
   numtcpsock| 177    -    - | 350    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    5
     numflock|   6    -    - |  45    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
       numpty|   -    -    - |   2    -    - | 488K| 488K|    -
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - | 309    -    - | 976K| 976K|    -
    tcpsndbuf|3.03M   2% 0.8%| 6.8M   3%   2%| 204M| 378M| 4.21M
    tcprcvbuf|2.77M   1% 0.7%|5.47M   2%   1%| 204M| 378M|  301
 othersockbuf| 486K 0.2% 0.1%|3.25M   2% 0.9%| 204M| 378M|   27
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - | 388K 0.2% 0.1%| 204M| 378M|    -
 numothersock| 231    -    - | 573    -    - |7.63M|7.63M|    -
   dcachesize|1.03M 0.1% 0.1%|1.83M 0.1% 0.1%|   2G|   2G|    -
      numfile|3.39K   -    - |11.2K   -    - |22.9M|22.9M|    7
    numiptent|  82    -    - | 323    -    - | 976K| 976K|    1
    swappages|   -    -    - |  24K   -    - |   - |   - |    -
```

My question is how do i optimize the containers so the load average will be back to normal instead of the high load i am facing right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, memory has nothing to do with load average.  [Take a few minutes and read up on the difference](https://serverfault.com/questions/67759/how-to-understand-the-memory-usage-and-load-average-in-linux-server).
Read all the linked reference material. It's important.
This answer will still be here when you're done.

---

You're back? OK good.

Now, what you need to know is this: **High load isn't a problem.**

Poor performance is a problem.
Crashes & freezes are a problem.
Running out of disk space is a problem.

If you're not having an actual *problem* don't obsess over the load number.
From a business standpoint the higher the load number the better -- If a system is operating well (that is, nobody is complaining) with a load average of 1000 then you're making efficient use of the system.
<sup>Note that I'm making a distinction between computationally efficient and efficient from a business standpoint.</sup>

---

If you *are* having an actual problem, like poor performance from the VMs, load average is *one* diagnostic tool to help you troubleshoot it (an indication of how many processes are waiting for the CPU).

You probably can't optimize your way out of this situation by tuning the VMs -- your system is demanding more work out of the CPU than it can do. A load average of 300 means you have 300 processes that want to be using the CPU (versus however many cores your system has), and that could very well mean the wait time is noticeable.
To correct this situation you need to remove load from the server (by migrating work - VMs - to another box).  Start by migrating the "heaviest" VMs (the ones that need the most CPU time), and keep removing load until the *system performance* meets your needs (regardless of the load average). Remember to leave yourself a little headroom in case the VM workloads change.

(For that matter if you *aren't* having problems but just can't get past having a high load number this is still the solution - remove load until the number makes you feel better.)