# Where is my RAM going?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, memory

I see only 370 MB (10%) free on an AWS Amazon Linux instance:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3752       3709         42          0        142        185
-/+ buffers/cache:       3381        370
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Here's the memory usage profile over the life of the box, which has never been rebooted:

[image]

I'm puzzled, because nothing seems to be using much RAM (this is a NAT box running no server software):

```
top - 23:40:52 up 41 days, 13:48,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks:  67 total,   1 running,  66 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.3%st
Mem:   3842636k total,  3799620k used,    43016k free,   146156k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   189716k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                     
31600 aws       20   0  348m  96m 4524 S  0.0  2.6  10:46.35 opsworks-agent                                                                                                                               
31579 aws       20   0  413m  95m 4240 S  0.0  2.6  86:25.29 opsworks-agent                                                                                                                               
31596 aws       20   0  401m  83m 4216 S  0.0  2.2  18:43.31 opsworks-agent                                                                                                                               
31575 aws       20   0  178m  56m 2084 S  0.0  1.5   9:09.03 opsworks-agent                                                                                                                               
31924 root      20   0  109m 4176 3180 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 sshd                                                                                                                                         
 1414 newrelic  20   0  102m 3656 2236 S  1.0  0.1  49:32.82 nrsysmond                                                                                                                                    
 1441 root      20   0 89216 2324  640 S  0.0  0.1   1:25.47 sendmail                                                                                                                                     
 1214 root      20   0  237m 2188  788 S  0.0  0.1   0:02.42 rsyslogd                                                                                                                                     
 1448 smmsp     20   0 80676 2048  612 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.99 sendmail                                                                                                                                     
 1382 ntp       20   0 31312 1972 1360 S  0.0  0.1   0:04.08 ntpd                                                                                                                                         
31926 ross      20   0  109m 1952  948 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                                                                         
31927 ross      20   0  112m 1948 1580 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 bash                                                                                                                                         
31472 root      20   0  121m 1632  928 S  0.0  0.0   4:12.10 monit                                                                                                                                        
 1292 root      20   0  463m 1620  988 S  0.0  0.0   0:35.47 automount                                                                                                                                    
    1 root      20   0 19480 1568 1248 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.36 init                                                                                                                                         
 1456 root      20   0  116m 1196  620 S  0.0  0.0   0:16.99 crond                                                                                                                                        
32150 ross      20   0 15124 1196  920 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 top                                                                                                                                          
 1363 root      20   0 79964 1160  384 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                                                                         
  668 root      20   0 10784  996  608 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 udevd                                                                                                                                        
 1153 root      20   0  9228  968  476 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.05 dhclient                                                                                                                                     
 1250 dbus      20   0 21628  796  564 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                                  
 1196 root      16  -4  111m  776  432 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.24 auditd                                                                                                                                       
 1504 root      20   0  6304  728  620 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 agetty                                                                                                                                       
  785 root      20   0 10780  640  280 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd                                                                                                                                        
  795 root      20   0 10780  580  220 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd                                                                                                                                        
 1514 root      20   0  4180  564  476 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                                                                     
 1523 root      20   0  4180  564  476 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                                                                     
 1510 root      20   0  4180  560  476 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                                                                     
 1516 root      20   0  4180  560  476 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                                                                     
 1518 root      20   0  4180  560  476 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                                                                     
 1521 root      20   0  4180  560  476 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                                                                     
 1466 root      20   0 16908  368  212 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 atd                                                                                                                                          
 1413 newrelic  20   0 26692  264   64 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nrsysmond                                                                                                                                    
 1230 root      20   0  4180   80    0 S  0.0  0.0   4:12.80 rngd                                                                                                                                         
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                     
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:23.38 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                  
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0                                                                                                                                  
    5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                                                                                                 
    6 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:23.99 kworker/u2:0                                                                                                                                 
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:18.81 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                    
    8 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                                                                                                                       
    9 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                                                                                  
   10 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper                                                                                                                                      
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                                                                                                    
   12 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                                                                        
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u2:1                                                                                                                                 
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xenwatch                                                                                                                                     
   20 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.00 xenbus
```

It looks like only 10% of RAM is being used, from this output:

```
$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  19480  1568 ?        Ss    2014   0:01 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:23 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:23 [kworker/u2:0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   2:18 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [migration/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [khelper]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [netns]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [kworker/u2:1]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [xenwatch]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:01 [xenbus]
root       112  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [writeback]
root       115  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN    2014   0:00 [ksmd]
root       116  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root       117  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [bioset]
root       118  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [crypto]
root       120  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [kblockd]
root       131  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [md]
root       218  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   1:24 [kworker/0:1]
root       233  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root       238  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:07 [kswapd0]
root       303  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root       317  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [kthrotld]
root       323  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [khvcd]
root       364  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [deferwq]
root       630  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:19 [jbd2/xvda1-8]
root       631  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       668  0.0  0.0  10784   996 ?        Ss    2014   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       785  0.0  0.0  10780   640 ?        S     2014   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       795  0.0  0.0  10780   580 ?        S     2014   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       971  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2014   0:00 [kauditd]
root      1024  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root      1153  0.0  0.0   9228   968 ?        Ss    2014   0:02 /sbin/dhclient -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid eth0
root      1196  0.0  0.0 113944   776 ?        Ssl  2014   0:05 auditd
root      1214  0.0  0.0 243280  2188 ?        Sl    2014   0:02 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
root      1230  0.0  0.0   4180    80 ?        Ss    2014   4:12 rngd --no-tpm=1 --quiet
dbus      1250  0.0  0.0  21628   796 ?        Ss    2014   0:00 dbus-daemon --system
root      1292  0.0  0.0 474260  1620 ?        Ssl   2014   0:35 automount --pid-file /var/run/autofs.pid
root      1363  0.0  0.0  79964  1160 ?        Ss    2014   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
ntp       1382  0.0  0.0  31312  1972 ?        Ss    2014   0:04 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g
newrelic  1413  0.0  0.0  26692   264 ?        Ss    2014   0:00 /usr/sbin/nrsysmond -c /etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg -p /var/run/newrelic/nrsysmond.pid
newrelic  1414  0.0  0.0 105204  3360 ?        Sl    2014  49:33 /usr/sbin/nrsysmond -c /etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg -p /var/run/newrelic/nrsysmond.pid
root      1441  0.0  0.0  89216  2324 ?        Ss    2014   1:25 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp     1448  0.0  0.0  80676  2048 ?        Ss    2014   0:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
root      1456  0.0  0.0 119356  1196 ?        Ss    2014   0:16 crond
root      1466  0.0  0.0  16908   368 ?        Ss    2014   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
root      1504  0.0  0.0   6304   728 hvc0     Ss+   2014   0:00 /sbin/agetty hvc0 38400 vt100-nav
root      1510  0.0  0.0   4180   560 tty1     Ss+   2014   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
root      1514  0.0  0.0   4180   564 tty2     Ss+   2014   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
root      1516  0.0  0.0   4180   560 tty3     Ss+   2014   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
root      1518  0.0  0.0   4180   560 tty4     Ss+   2014   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
root      1521  0.0  0.0   4180   560 tty5     Ss+   2014   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
root      1523  0.0  0.0   4180   564 tty6     Ss+   2014   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
root      1738  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    2014   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root     31472  0.0  0.0 124884  1632 ?        Sl    2014   4:12 monit
aws      31575  0.0  1.4 181608 57312 ?        Sl    2014   9:09 opsworks-agent: master 31575                                     
aws      31579  0.2  2.5 423204 98124 ?        Sl    2014  86:26 opsworks-agent: keep_alive of master 31575                       
aws      31596  0.0  2.2 410856 85616 ?        Sl    2014  18:43 opsworks-agent: statistics of master 31575                       
aws      31600  0.0  2.5 356956 98612 ?        Sl    2014  10:46 opsworks-agent: process_command of master 31575                  
root     31924  0.0  0.1 111640  4176 ?        Ss   23:28   0:00 sshd: ross [priv]
ross     31926  0.0  0.0 111640  1952 ?        S    23:28   0:00 sshd: ross@pts/0 
ross     31927  0.0  0.0 115152  1952 pts/0    Ss   23:28   0:00 -bash
ross     32240  0.0  0.0 117048  1208 pts/0    R+   23:45   0:00 ps aux
ross     32241  0.0  0.0    240     4 pts/0    D+   23:45   0:00 [sed]
```

Am I misinterpreting these metrics? Any idea how I can determine what's using 90% of my RAM when it seems like only 10% is being used?

**NOTE:** I believe this is not a duplicate of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/67759/how-to-understand-the-memory-usage-and-load-average-in-linux-server) question, as my RAM is not being consumed by disk cache (according to `free`).

**UPDATE 1** – output of `slabtop`:

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 15746067 / 15766743 (99.9%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 750727 / 750727 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 64 / 88 (72.7%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 2978870.88K / 2981599.96K (99.9%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.19K / 8.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
15556863 15556863 100%    0.19K 740803       21   2963212K dentry
 81705  73173  89%    0.10K   2095   39  8380K buffer_head
 43728  43728 100%    0.95K   5466        8     43728K ext4_inode_cache
 22525  22525 100%    0.05K    265   85  1060K shared_policy_node
 13668   5466  39%    0.04K    134  102   536K ext4_extent_status
  7098   7098 100%    0.55K    507   14  4056K inode_cache
  6188   6188 100%    0.12K    182   34   728K kernfs_node_cache
  5568   4768  85%    0.06K     87   64   348K kmalloc-64
  4606   3204  69%    0.55K    329   14  2632K radix_tree_node
  3190   3190 100%    0.18K    145   22   580K vm_area_struct
  2856   1567  54%    0.19K    136   21   544K kmalloc-192
  2496   2496 100%    0.06K     39   64   156K anon_vma
  2048   2048 100%    0.01K  4  512        16K kmalloc-8
  1680   1680 100%    0.07K     30   56   120K ext4_io_end
  1536   1536 100%    0.03K     12  128        48K kmalloc-32
  1280   1280 100%    0.02K  5  256        20K kmalloc-16
  1232    980  79%    0.25K     77   16   308K kmalloc-256
  1050   1050 100%    0.09K     25   42   100K kmalloc-96
   966    966 100%    0.09K     21   46        84K ftrace_event_file
   720    720 100%    0.11K     20   36        80K jbd2_journal_head
   640    640 100%    0.12K     20   32        80K kmalloc-128
   600    600 100%    0.62K     24   25   384K proc_inode_cache
   512    512 100%    0.03K  4  128        16K jbd2_revoke_record_s
   408    408 100%    0.64K     34   12   272K shmem_inode_cache
   400    399  99%    0.50K     50        8   200K kmalloc-512
   256    256 100%    0.02K  1  256         4K jbd2_revoke_table_s
   248    218  87%    1.00K     31        8   248K kmalloc-1024
   169    113  66%    0.30K     13   13        52K nf_conntrack_ffffffff81aa5940
   168    168 100%    0.07K  3   56        12K eventpoll_pwq
   150    136  90%    1.06K     10   15   160K signal_cache
   144    127  88%    2.00K     18        8   288K kmalloc-2048
   144    144 100%    0.11K  4   36        16K task_delay_info
   135    135 100%    2.06K  9   15   288K sighand_cache
   128    128 100%    0.06K  2   64         8K kmem_cache_node
   128    128 100%    0.06K  2   64         8K ext4_free_data
   120     60  50%    4.00K     15        8   480K kmalloc-4096
   108    108 100%    0.62K  9   12        72K files_cache
   108    108 100%    0.88K     12        9        96K mm_struct
   100     89  89%    6.33K     20        5   640K task_struct
   100     90  90%    0.38K     10   10        40K blkdev_requests
    96     96 100%    0.25K  6   16        24K kmem_cache
    96     96 100%    0.25K  6   16        24K tw_sock_TCP
    90     90 100%    2.06K  6   15   192K idr_layer_cache
    90     90 100%    0.13K  3   30        12K ext4_allocation_context
    85     85 100%    0.05K  1   85         4K jbd2_journal_handle
    73     73 100%    0.05K  1   73         4K ip_fib_trie
```

**UPDATE 2** – output of `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:        3842636 kB
MemFree:          148572 kB
MemAvailable:    3542752 kB
Buffers:          151816 kB
Cached:           247564 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           513568 kB
Inactive:         115604 kB
Active(anon):     229796 kB
Inactive(anon):       12 kB
Active(file):     283772 kB
Inactive(file):   115592 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                28 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        229820 kB
Mapped:            11060 kB
Shmem:                16 kB
Slab:            3031636 kB
SReclaimable:    3024180 kB
SUnreclaim:         7456 kB
KernelStack:         672 kB
PageTables:         4360 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1921316 kB
Committed_AS:     465112 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:        7532 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359727383 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     3940352 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB
```

Comment: Use `slabtop` to see if it's the dentry cache.

Comment: Yes, it's the dentry cache. See the answer to the linked question.